# VHDL gray code counter

Tags: vhdl, gray-code

I'm trying to implement a gray code counter using a shift register and a 4-1 MUX. Does anyone have an idea what logic to use?!

Thanks

Comment: I'm having a hard time not adding the snarky answer of "boolean".  Can you describe your approach and how it's failing?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this satisfies your requirement of "using a shift register and a 4-1 MUX", but here is a small and functional gray counter reference design by Altera:

https://www.altera.com/support/support-resources/design-examples/design-software/vhdl/vhd-gray-counter.html

Comment: The url looks dead? Care to update?